# Issues with .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I 've been monkeying around with alternate solutions for my expand/collapse accordion bars for a while now and can't seem to come up with a proper function to replace the trigger words "Open" with "Close" when necessary.

I know this is simple stuff, and in a year hopefully I'll look back and laugh. Until then, any quick help with the jsFiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/mtubb/` from someone more experienced then I would be very helpful.

Comment: Where are you initializing your accordion? $( "#accordion" ).accordion()?

Comment: Check your syntax, you are missing a opening bracket after the else.

Comment: I'm not using an accordion plugin, just jQuery's slideToggle to show/hide content, the script should run on document ready, is this what you are asking me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you're making it :-)

I've updated (and forked) your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/mtubb/13/). Using a ternary operator, you can just toggle the text in one line.

A ternary operator is short-hand for an if-else statement:

```
var value = (condition == true) ? trueValue : falseValue
```

Can be written as:

```
if(condition == true)
{
    var value = trueValue;
}
else
{
    var value = falseValue;
}
```

Hopefully what the code below does is reasonably apparent; if the `span`'s content is `Close`, it's changed to `Open`, and *vice versa*.

```
$('.accord-bar').append("<span>Close</span>");

$('.accord-bar').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');

    $(this).find("span").text(($(this).find("span").text() == "Open") ? "Close" : "Open");

    $(this).next('.pairing').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Wahoo! Thanks so much... #ternaryoperatorsslashjamwafflesFTW

Comment: Not a problem Allison :-) Glad I could be of service!

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code in the fiddle you provided and here is the link to the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/SamirAdel/mtubb/25/